# Index \see command not italicized in french document

Tags: xetex, indexing, imakeidx, french

I'm using `imakeidx` and `polyglossia` packages, main language: french.

I have a nice small index with some `\see` commands. But the word “voir“ (“see“ in french) printed in the document is not in italics.

I tried out the commands below in the preamble:

```
\newcommand*\see[2]{\emph{\seename} #1}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\seename}{\emph{voir}}
```

but nothing changes.

I made a test by changing the main language to english, and it works well with “see” in italics.

Could someone kindly help me ?
Thanks

PS : here is a minimal example…

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{imakeidx} \makeindex

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla\index{word-A}.

\index{word-AA|see{word-A}}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use this in your preamble: `\def\see{\emph{voir}~}`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your suggestion, but the inconvenient about this solution is that it adds a page number to the "see" index entry, which is not the desired behavior. But I realized that maybe I didn't expressed myself correctly, because the problem here is not about the `\see` command, as I said, but the `\index` command with the following syntax:`\index{a|see{b}}`. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in `gloss-french.ldf`, which has

```
\def\seename{\emph{voir}}%
\def\alsoname{\emph{voir aussi}}%
```

in the code for `\captionsfrench`. The `\emph` should be removed, because it is already in the standard definition of `\see`.

What happens is that `\see{word-A}{1}` in the `.ind` file becomes, according to the standard definition of `\see`,

```
\emph{\seename} word-A
```

which in turn becomes

```
\emph{\emph{voir}} word-A
```

and double emphasis chooses upright type. You can choose one of the following fixes:

1. `\appto\captionsfrench{\def\seename{voir}\def\alsoname{voir aussi}}`
2. `\renewcommand{\see}[2]{\seename\ #1}`

The former method fixes the wrong setting made by `polyglossia`; the latter just avoids double emphasis.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations and the proposed solutions. The fix number 1 works perfectly ! However the fix number 2 deletes the space after "voir". Maybe the reason is that the problem here is not exactly about the `\see` command (see above my reply to Bernard)...

Comment: @gabrielpdp1979 Yes, you're right! A backslash was missing.